# how to include unreferenced exes/dlls from solution in setup and bin - VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I have a solution with multiple projects - combination of exes and dlls.

I'm fairly new to setup projects.

I have an event log installer (exe) which I run on the client machine during installation - a custom action which is working fine.

This project is in the solution and is not referenced by any other project.

How do I set this to be:

1. automatically be copied to bin folder  of the main project - first of all is it a normal practice to do this way? If not, where do you copy unreferenced exes/dlls - loaded during runtime?
2. automatically be included in the setup project when I include primary output of the main project.

I checked the project in the Build Configuration Manager - nothing has changed. I still have to copy manually.

Thanks

Comment: There's a custom build step you can run, but maybe it's only a hotfix, not proper way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding project outputs to deployment projects, you can add files to a deployment project:  ["How to add items to a deployment project"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z11b431t.aspx).  That tells:

"To add a merge module or assembly to a deployment project Select the deployment project in Solution Explorer.  On the Project menu, point to Add, and then click Merge Module or click Assembly. In the resulting dialog box, select the item that you want to add."  You can direct the extra files to various symbolic target locations, such as your target Program Files folder.

But since it's a log installer you need, you may want to install it as a prerequisite project: ["How to install prerequisites"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5)

And finally, you may need to look at "Custom actions" which can be added to any install step and pretty much take care of anything else you need.